# Building sfnetwork in R throwing an error message

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf, network-analysis, sfnetwork

I am trying to build a road network by using sfnetworks package in R, and I ran into an issue while running the last code chunk.

The below is my R code and [data](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tSMAVv-Tcr_hfw4Fxy4BM5yimxZazl-b?usp=sharing) available here:

```
# Read in Data

## London borough boundary
LondonBoroughs <- st_read(here::here('data', 'boundary', 'London_Borough_Excluding_MHW.shp')) %>%
  st_transform(., 27700)

## street nodes
street_nodes <- st_read(here::here('data', 'cleaned_nodes.geojson')) %>% st_transform(., 27700)


## street edges
street_edges <- st_read(here::here('data', 'cleaned_edges.geojson')) %>% st_transform(., 27700)
```

The street_nodes variable has 6 columns and osmid(int64) as row index: y(float64), x(float64), highway(object), ref(object), geometry(geometry).

The street_edges variable has 12 columns: u(int64), v(int64), key(int64), osmid(object), oneway(boolean), length(float64), from(int64), to(int64), junction(object), area(object), landuse(object), geometry(geomtery)

```
# Data cleaning

## remove duplicate street nodes - no duplicates
street_nodes <- street_nodes %>%
  distinct()

## street nodes within London boundary
street_nodes <- street_nodes[LondonBoroughs, ]

## street edges within London boundary
street_edges <- street_edges[LondonBoroughs, ]

## remove duplicate street edges - no duplicates
street_edges <- street_edges %>%
  distinct()
```

```
# create network
net = sfnetwork(street_nodes, street_edges, directed = FALSE)
```

When I run the last code chunk, it throws the following error message:

***Error in (function (edges, n = max(edges), directed = TRUE) :
At core/graph/type_indexededgelist.c:117 : Number of vertices must not be negative. Invalid value***

The below are what I did in Python:

I queried the OSM road networks in Python and did a bit of data preprocessing, such as converting datatype and filling na values. The initially preprocessed edge and node data were saved in geojson format.

```
import os
import wget
import osmnx as ox
import geopandas as gpd

# bounding box of London
bbox = (-0.5108706, 51.28117, 0.322123, 51.68948)

# get road network and save as .shp
G = ox.graph_from_bbox(bbox[3], bbox[1], bbox[2], bbox[0], network_type='all')

ox.save_graph_shapefile(G, filepath='data/london_street/raw_osm_data', encoding='utf-8')

# load as GeoDataFrame
nodes = gpd.read_file('data/london_street/raw_osm_data/nodes.shp')
edges = gpd.read_file('data/london_street/raw_osm_data/edges.shp')

# node column rename
nodes.rename(columns = {'street_cou' : 'street_count'}, inplace = True)

# replace 'None' to empty string in node data
nodes.fillna("",inplace=True)

cleaned_nodes = nodes.copy()
cleaned_nodes.set_index('osmid', inplace = True)
cleaned_nodes.head(3)


# replace 'None' to empty string in edge data
edges.fillna("",inplace=True)

# select columns of interest
cleaned_edges = edges[['u', 'v', 'key', 'osmid', 'oneway', 'length', 'from', 'to', 'junction',
       'area', 'landuse', 'geometry']].copy()
cleaned_edges.head(1)

# convert 'oneway' datatype to boolean
cleaned_edges['oneway'] = cleaned_edges['oneway'].astype(bool)

# save the cleaned nodes and edges
file_path_nodes = "data/london_street/cleaned_osm_data/cleaned_nodes.geojson"
cleaned_nodes.to_file(file_path_nodes, driver = "GeoJSON")

file_path_edges = "data/london_street/cleaned_osm_data/cleaned_edges.geojson"
cleaned_edges.to_file(file_path_edges, driver = "GeoJSON")
```

In case, the function assumes that there should be nodes for every integer between min(street_nodes$osmid) (2) and max(street_nodes$osmid) I experimented to change the datatypes of "to" and "from" columns in edge data and 'osmid' column in node data to a 'character' type. But nothing worked and still got the same error message.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The problem seems to be either with your original file, or one of your preprocessing steps, which makes it difficult to provide specific advice. Two questions: 1. Have you checked/fixed the validity of your geometry with [`st_make_valid()`](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/valid.html). 2. What is your overall goal after building the road network? I've done a lot of work with London roads from R using osrm and haven't run into these kinds of problems. Might be worth considering, depending what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Sam.
Regarding your questions,
1) I checked the validity of geometry and both data seem fine. The node is in point and the edge is in linestring geometry.
2) Once I build the network, I am planning on projecting POIs to the network, and calculating the travel distance/time to the POIs.

I googled if anyone ran into this issue, but I did not find anyone who experienced the same problem as I did...

Comment: The shapefile I read in R is London Boundary data from London Data Store! I wanted to clip street_edges and street_nodes to the London boundary so I also read in the boundary data to do spatial subsetting:)

Comment: I don't see an obvious problem, but your workflow seems a little odd. For an alternative approach to calculating road distances to specific points in R using osrm see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75791459/r-calculating-the-distance-between-two-geographical-points/). For converting a shapefile to an `sfnetwork` object directly in R, without preprocessing in Python or splitting nodes and edges see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75923204/calculating-distances-between-points-on-a-shapefile/76102963#76102963).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!
I will have a read at the posts:)

Comment: Do you face the same problem with other bounding boxes? And could you replicate the error using smaller datasets? If so, could you share them?